# I am got a import error when using tensorflow-gpu

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "D:\Program Files\Python3.6.5\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>  
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *  
  File "D:\Program Files\Python3.6.5\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>  
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()  
  File "D:\Program Files\Python3.6.5\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper  
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)  
  File "D:\Program Files\Python3.6.5\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)  
  File "D:\Program Files\Python3.6.5\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)  
ImportError: DLL load failed: can't find the module。
```

and here is my pip list:

```
Package              Version  
-------------------- -------  
absl-py              0.7.0  
astor                0.7.1  
cycler               0.10.0  
et-xmlfile           1.0.1  
gast                 0.2.2  
grpcio               1.19.0  
h5py                 2.9.0  
jdcal                1.4  
Keras-Applications   1.0.7  
Keras-Preprocessing  1.0.9  
kiwisolver           1.0.1  
Markdown             3.0.1  
matplotlib           3.0.3  
mock                 2.0.0  
numpy                1.16.2  
openpyxl             2.6.1  
pandas               0.24.1  
pbr                  5.1.3  
pip                  19.0.3  
protobuf             3.7.0  
pyparsing            2.3.1  
python-dateutil      2.8.0  
pytz                 2018.9  
PyYAML               3.13  
setuptools           40.6.2  
six                  1.12.0  
tensorboard          1.13.1  
tensorflow           1.13.1  
tensorflow-estimator 1.13.0  
tensorflow-gpu       1.13.1  
termcolor            1.1.0  
Werkzeug             0.14.1  
wheel                0.33.1
```

and the cuda vervsion:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2018 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Jun_12_23:08:12_Central_Daylight_Time_2018
Cuda compilation tools, release 9.2, V9.2.148
```

same one can help me? thanks a lot.

Comment: I am unsure, please correct me if I am wrong, but doesn't tensorflow need CUDA 9.0?

Comment: I correct myself, the webpage seems to suggest CUDA 10 is needed for 1.13.0

Comment: I tried the following versions 8.0, 9.0 9.2, 10

Comment: fixed: change the python from 3.7 to 3.5, and install tensorflow-gpu==1.12.0 instead of 1.13.1, thanks a lot.